# PHP DateTime: Get next sunday from a specific timestamp

Tags: php, date, datetime

I was searching for the right answer but I was unable to find it. 
What I need to find out is, how to get the next sunday from a given timestamp?

My scenario is that I have a timestamp saved inside my database.

```
$timestamp='1530223200';
```

The timestamp stands for friday, 29.june.2018 00:00:00!
I now need to get the next sunday (also 00:00:00) from the given timestamp. In my scenario it would be sunday, 01.july.2018 00:00:00!

Any idea how I can to this?

EDIT:
Here is what I´ve right now:

```
function listYearWeeksProbierbox($year) {

        $weeks=array();
        $timestamp='1530223200';
        $run_stamp = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', $timestamp));
        $run_stamp->modify('next sunday');
        $run_stamp->format('Y-m-d');

        for ($x=0;$x<7;$x++) {
            if (date("w",$run_stamp)==0) { // Montag
                if ($weeks[date("W",$run_stamp)]=="") {
                    $weeks[date("W",$run_stamp)]=$run_stamp;
                }
            }
            $run_stamp=($run_stamp+86400);
        }

        return $weeks;

}
```

Problem is I do get the following error message:

```
Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: comfortable with external library then you can use Carbon::parse('next Sunday')?

Comment: Why would you use `date()` and `strtotime()` functions when you are using `DateTime` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
$timestamp = '1530223200';
$date = new DateTime("@$timestamp");
$date->modify('next sunday');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I edited my post so that you can see my current function. It is not working as you´ve suggested. Any idea what I did wrong?